# Reference request. Finiteness of the Selmer group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, abelian-varieties, rational-points, global-fields

Let $K$ be a global field (ie either a number field or the function field of a curve over a finite field). Let $A,B$ be abelian varieties over $K$ and let $\phi:A\to B$ be an isogeny. Associated with $\phi$ is the well-known Selmer group ${\rm Sel}(\phi)\subseteq H^1(K,{\rm ker}(\phi))$, which contains $B(K)/\phi(A(K))$. It is classical that this group is finite but I couldn't find a reference in the situation where $K$ has positive characteristic. I have it in my memory that J. Milne proved this in the early 1970s but I wasn't able to find the corresponding article. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at this paper of Kestutis Cesnavicius: https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~kestutis.cesnavicius/selmer-flat.pdf? I think one ought to be able to adapt the usual char 0 proof, which involves the fact that the group of cohomology classes that are unramified outside a finite set of primes is finite, to the positive char case by working with fppf cohomology. The main theorem in the linked paper has some extra assumptions, but I believe that the finiteness should be extractable in full generality. Have a look, in particular, at Section 5.

Comment: Sorry about the rushed comment! I am writing from memory. I can check this myself later and may leave a proper answer.

Comment: @Alex B. Thank you for this! I will have a look. I thought this was not a recent result, though.

Comment: Perhaps not directly relevant but I should also mention this paper of Brian Conrad on finiteness of Sha over global function fields: https://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/cosetfinite.pdf

Comment: @David Benjamin Lim. Thank you for this reference. I will have a look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The paper is  Milne, J. S. Elements of order p in the Tate-Šafarevič group. Bull. London Math. Soc. 2 (1970), 293–296. He deduces his statement about the Tate-Shafarevich group from a statement about the Selmer group. He also notes that if you omit any places in the definition of these groups, then you may get infinitely many elements of order p.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! This is indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: The case when the characteristic of the field is coprime to the degree of the isogeny is of course older, like Theorem 5 in Lang-Tate. (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372778)

Comment: @Chris Wuthrich. Yes of course. My question was really for the inseparable case.